# Excel formula to apply penalty column to ranking

Tags: excel, rank

I have thought long and hard about this, but I can't find a solution to what I believe is quite a simple problem.

I have a table of results, where sometimes someone will be given a penalty of a varying amount. This is entered into the penalty column (Col C).

I need a formula which checks if there is an entry into the penalty column and applies it, **not only to that row, but to the number of subsequent rows which are affected, depending on the severity of the penalty**.

I have tried to see if this is possible by referencing the penalty against the 'ROW()' function but have not been able to achieve the desired effect.

Col D shows the desired output of the formula.

Col E is included for reference only, to show the desired effect on each row.

```
Col A    Col B      Col C      Col D     Col E
Pos      Name       Penalty    New Pos   Change
1        Jack                  1         0
2        Matt                  2         0
3        Daniel     2          5         +2
4        Gordon                3         -1
5        Phillip               4         -1
6        Günther               6         0
7        Johann     3          10        +3
8        Alain                 7         -1
9        John                  8         -1
10       Gianmaria             9         -1
```

The big issue is, if someone is handed a big penalty, for example '10' then it affects the following ten rows. I can't work out how to include this variable logic...

I would be interested to hear the approach of others...

Comment: What if a player gets 10 penalty, but there is only two players below? Is it five each or still only one each?

Comment: In that case the person just goes to the bottom of the list - i.e. if they were originally P5, get 10 penalty but there are only 10 people, then they go to P10.

Comment: What happens if two or more people are penalised such that their resulting positions are the same? For example, the player in 1st position is penalised 3 positions and the player in 2nd position is penalised 2 positions?

Comment: The player who had the best original position would be ranked higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the RANK() function:

[Excel RANK Function Examples](http://www.contextures.com/excel-functions-rank.html)

In a new column, add the penalty value to the original position, plus a small coeffieient depending on the original position (0.01 per increment perhaps) to move the penalised player below the original person at that position, then in the next column you can RANK() the new column of values (F in my case).

New value is therefore =A2+(IF(C2>0,C2+(0.01*A2)))

Rank is then =RANK(F2,F2:F11,1)

You can combine all the functions into one, but it's clearer to do it in separate columns at first.

Comment: Edited to remove clashing values.  The coefficient needs to be smaller than 1/candidates to avoid it overflowing. So I've chosen 0.01, so even a penalty for the 10th placed candidate will only have an additional 0.1 added, which won't affect their ranking by a whole integer.

Comment: Great - but what if the data is set out in such a way that it is like a flat-file database (with the results for the next game directly below in rows 10-20)? i.e. if in a new first column we actually had a `GameID` column, and in your second formula we needed to limit the `F2:F11` part to only the rows which matched the `GameID'. Could this formula also accept an index-match for the range? That way the formula could be dragged down over 10,000s of rows, all containing unique game data...

Comment: I will try using an index-match function.

Comment: Something like `=RANK(F2,INDEX(F:F,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)),1)` ?

Comment: Instead of using rank, index or match I produced the desired result with the following formula `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,U:U,"<"&F2)+1` where column A has been added after my original question to hold the unique `GameID`.